# Is this the correct way to start an Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

```
Intent nnn = new Intent(Hello.this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(nnn);
finish();
```

This would start a new activity, and then close the current Activity ***forever***, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes. finish should stop the activity. The onDestroy() happens when its called.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29

Answer (score 1):

Yes,Calling finish() should stop  your current activity and start new activity.